# Only one of two delegate functions working

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I am trying to delegate a click action but it only works this way:

```
$('input#doIt').on('click',  { name: "Karl" } , function(event){
    alert(event.data.name);

});
```

but not this way:

```
$('input').on('click', '#doIt' , { name: "Karl" } , function(event){
    alert(event.data.name);
});
```

According to the documentation they should be the same. The first one only binds to one element while the second one binds to two, but the selector so reduce it to one. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here is the html

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="formLabel">Add Node:</div>
     <div class="formInput"> <input type="text" name="addNote"></div>
  </div>
<div id="goTo" class="row"><input id="doIt" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the documentation they should be the same.

No, [the documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the selector filters *descendants*, not the actual element you hooked the event on:

> **selector**
>
> Type: `String`
>
> A selector string to filter ***the descendants of*** the selected elements that trigger the event.

(My emphasis) In your case, the `input` with the `id` `doIt` isn't a descendant, you're hooking the event directly to it.

You'd use the delegated form by hooking the event on an ancestor of the `doIt` `input`, probably on whatever contains your `div.row` elements:

```
$("selector for the container of the rows").on('click', '#doIt', {name: "Karl"}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.name);
});
```

(I'm assuming you have a good reason for using delegation for this, rather than just hooking directly to the `doIt` element — for example, perhaps that element gets removed and recreated frequently.)

Comment: Yeah, I was using delegate because I eventually want to create this form in javascript and append it to the document dynamically. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the first one is working because you are using direct on event and not delegating it to any of its parent element

```
$('input#doIt').on('click',  { name: "Karl" } , function(event){
```

here, you are just calling the click event for the input whose id is `doIt`, **which will not work if the input is added dynamically..**

and in your second, you are delegating but then to the same element..

```
$('input').on('click', '#doIt' , { name: "Karl" } , function(event){
  alert(event.data.name);
});
```

here, this will call click event to all elements whose id is `doIt`  **inside an input which is not correct**

you need to delegate it to the closest static parent container.. so this will work..

```
 $('div#goTo').on('click', 'input#doIt' , { name: "Karl" } , function(event){
   ...
```

<strike>**note: you have two elements with same Id `doIt` which is invalid HTML.. change one to class.. i changed the input to class here in above code.**</strike>

Comment: *"you have two elements with same Id doIt which is invalid HTML"* No, he has a `div` called `goTo` and an `input` called `doIt`.

Comment: damn!!! sorry about that ... i read it as doIt.. i don't know how... anywyas thanks.. ;)...i will be updating that..